# Null Point exception in Tomee log when tried to deploy message driven bean

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

I have written message driven bean. What I am new to JMS and trying to learn Message driven beans. Mostly EJB 3.x specification. I am trying to deploy the jar created for following class.

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(name="xxx", activationConfig =  {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                                  propertyValue = "/queue/helloQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                                  propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
public class JMSListner implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("message received");
    }

}
```

tomee.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
<!-- JMS configuration -->
<Container id="ExeJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">

   ResourceAdapter = ExeJmsResourceAdapter

  # Specifies the maximum number of bean instances that are
  # allowed to exist for each MDB deployment.

  InstanceLimit = 1000

  StrictPooling = false

</Container>

  <Resource id="ExeJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?daemon=true)?persistent=false&amp;deleteAllMessagesOnStartup=true
        DataSource =
    </Resource>

   <Resource id="fiper/jms/connectionfactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
      ResourceAdapter = ExeJmsResourceAdapter
      TransactionSupport xa
      PoolMaxSize 15000
   </Resource>

   <Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
      ResourceAdapter = ExeJmsResourceAdapter
   </Resource>

<!-- JMS Queues used by demo -->
   <Resource id="helloQueue" type="javax.jms.Queue">
      Destination helloQueue
   </Resource>
<Resource id="TestDS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpadb
    UserName    root
    Password    ######1Aa
</Resource>



  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->

<!-- activeMQ activation placeholder -->

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
  <!-- <Deployments dir="apps" /> -->

<Deployments dir="apps/" />
</tomee>
```

Getting an exception when I start startup.bat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl$PersistenceClassFileTransformer.transform(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:358)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceBootstrap$Transformer.transform(PersistenceBootstrap.java:429)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadAndInitializeInvokerClass(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:282)
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadMethod(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:274)
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.generateCustomizedCode(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:616)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:629)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:248)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:104)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:109)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.resolve(LambdaForm.java:1053)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:20 PM org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport doStart
INFO: Listening for connections at: tcp://RKPWIN764PLP:61616?daemon=true
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Lazy.<clinit>(DirectMethodHandle.java:689)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:232)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:20 PM org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector start
INFO: Connector tcp://RKPWIN764PLP:61616?daemon=true started
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:1656)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:20 PM org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService doStartBroker
INFO: Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:RKPWIN764PLP-62595-1447768580766-0:1) started
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethod(MethodHandles.java:1601)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:20 PM org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService doStartBroker
INFO: For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findStatic(MethodHandles.java:778)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Factory.makeCbmhCtor(BoundMethodHandle.java:817)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Factory.makeCtors(BoundMethodHandle.java:772)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$SpeciesData.initForBootstrap(BoundMethodHandle.java:358)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$SpeciesData.<clinit>(BoundMethodHandle.java:447)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle.<clinit>(BoundMethodHandle.java:829)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.createIdentityForms(LambdaForm.java:1753)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.<clinit>(LambdaForm.java:1808)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:223)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:1656)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodNoSecurityManager(MethodHandles.java:1613)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodForConstant(MethodHandles.java:1798)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1747)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NullPointerException
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:21 PM org.apache.openejb.resource.activemq.ActiveMQ5Factory$1 run
INFO: Starting ActiveMQ checkpoint
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl$PersistenceClassFileTransformer.transform(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:358)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceBootstrap$Transformer.transform(PersistenceBootstrap.java:429)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadAndInitializeInvokerClass(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:282)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:21 PM org.apache.openejb.resource.activemq.ActiveMQ5Factory createBroker
INFO: ActiveMQ broker started
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadMethod(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:274)
        at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.generateCustomizedCode(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:616)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:629)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:248)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:21 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=TestDS)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:104)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:109)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.resolve(LambdaForm.java:1053)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Lazy.<clinit>(DirectMethodHandle.java:689)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:232)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:1656)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethod(MethodHandles.java:1601)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findStatic(MethodHandles.java:778)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Factory.makeCbmhCtor(BoundMethodHandle.java:817)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Factory.makeCtors(BoundMethodHandle.java:772)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$SpeciesData.initForBootstrap(BoundMethodHandle.java:358)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$SpeciesData.<clinit>(BoundMethodHandle.java:447)
        at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle.<clinit>(BoundMethodHandle.java:829)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.createIdentityForms(LambdaForm.java:1753)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.<clinit>(LambdaForm.java:1808)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:223)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:188)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:177)
        at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:84)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:1656)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodNoSecurityManager(MethodHandles.java:1613)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodForConstant(MethodHandles.java:1798)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1747)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
Nov 17, 2015 7:26:21 PM org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource readOnly
INFO: Disabling testOnBorrow since no validation query is provided
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl$PersistenceClassFileTransformer.transform(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:358)
```

Not sure what is wrong in the configuration or the MDB I have written. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a chance to test against tomee 7 (SNAPSHOT or the one in vote ATM: https://repository.apache.org/#nexus-search;gav~org.apache.tomee~apache-tomee~~~~kw,versionexpand) I guess this has been fixed.